# Intermittently, I get screenshots of 0 bytes after pressing Alt-PrintScreen

Tags: screenshot, gnome-screenshot, print-screen

I use **Alt-PrintScreen** to capture screen-dumps of windows. This often works well.

But frequently, it will not, and the only thing that happens, is that a screen dump image is created in `~/Pictures/` folder of size 0 bytes.

OS: 21.04

GPU: nVidia

Driver: NVIDIA 460.80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file with 0 bytes will be created if no tab/window is selected when using `Alt + PrintScreen`, you can use `Shift + PrintScreen` to capture the area you selected

---

You might also recheck/reset your keyboard shortcuts

> Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Seach `screenshot`